# How to check if the header contains the string "example@example.com"?

Tags: python

I want to check if the From header contains the email address noreply@youtube.com:

```
if msg['From'] =='noreply@youtube.com':
  count+=1
```

This does not add one to the count because the header actually contains 'YouTube noreply@youtube.com'.

How can I adapt my code so it adds one to the counter, checking that it contains 'noreply@youtube.com' anywhere in the header?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `in`.

```
>>> "noreply@youtube.com" in 'YouTube_noreply@youtube.com'
True
```